# Add a Buy Now button on product detail page along with Add to cart

Tags: magento-1.9

I want following actions to work on

- Add to cart will add product in the cart only.
- Buy Now will directly redirect the customer to the checkout page skipping cart step.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite  you can do this magento two process

### Process One:

one  is rewrite the class `Mage_Checkout_CartController` and in this `addAction()` at code `if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {` add `redirection` code     `$this->_redirect('checkout/onepage');`

## Process two:

Using event/Observer

Event:

```
checkout_cart_add_product_complete
```

This event provide the data of product object and cart request parameters

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
    array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
);
```

**Config.xml code:**

```
<frontend>
    <events>
    <checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
             <observers>
             <packagename_modulename_observer>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>packagename_modulename/observer</class>
                  <method>addToCartComplete</method>
             </packagename_modulename_observer>
             </observers>
         </checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
     </events>
</frontend>
```

**Observer code:**

using this event you can `set  your return url`

`$observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->setParam('return_url',Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'));` this redirect to you at checkout Onepage
function:

```
public function addToCartComplete(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
 $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
 $Request=$observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
 $Request->setParam('return_url',Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'));
}
```

this redirect to you at Checkout onepage

Comment: Will this work with items with custom option and configurable?